# error in replace one letter to null, then compare it with number in javaScript and cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

i tried to read price form webPage through cypress to convert $49.99 to 49.99 to be able to compare it with 40.00

with this code

```
  cy.get('.s-item').find('.s-item__price').invoke('text')
  .each(txt => txt.replace(/\$/g, '').then(parseFloat).should('be.gt', 40.00) // true
.and('be.lt',100.00 )    // true
```

and i get this error

```
      cy.each() can only operate on an array like subject. Your subject was: $49.99
```

then i tried to remove each

```
   cy.get('.s-item').find('.s-item__price').invoke('text')
  .then(txt => txt.replace(/\$/g, '').then(parseFloat).should('be.gt', 40.00) // true
.and('be.lt',100.00 )    // true
```

and i get this error

```
     txt.replace(...).then is not a function
```

how to solve it?

Comment: In your second try, you are missing a `)` after the replace to close off the first `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case it happens because `invoke` calls for jQuery *`text`* function, however `each` iterates through an array like structure (arrays or objects with a length property) - [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Syntax).

I suggest you next solution:

```
 cy.get('.s-item').find('.s-item__price').each(($el) => {
    expect(parseFloat($el.text().replace(/\$/g, ''))).to.be.greaterThan(40)
        .but.to.be.lessThan(100);
 )}
```

Comment: thank you expected 49.99 to be a number or a date, i get this error

Comment: argh, is my mistake. I have missed `parseFloat`. Please see my updated answer.